# Replacing values in specific columns in a Pandas Dataframe, when number of columns are unknown

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am brand new to Python and stacks exchange. I have been trying to replace invalid values ( x<-3 and x>12) with np.nan in specific columns.

I don't know how many columns I will have to deal with and thus will have to create a general code that takes this into account. I do however know, that the first two columns are ids and names respectively. I have searched google and stacks exchange for a solution but haven't been able to find a solution that solves my specific objective.

My question is; How would one replace values found in the third column and onwards?

My dataframe looks like this;

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJlL.png)

I tried this line:

```
Data[Data > 12.0] = np.nan.
```

this replaced the first two columns with nan

[1st attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7QJd.png)

I tried this line:

```
Data[(Data.iloc[(range(2,Columns))] >=12) & (Data.iloc[(range(2,Columns))]<=-3)] = np.nan
```

where,

```
Columns = len(Data.columns)
```

This is clearly wrong replacing all values in rows 2 to 6 (Columns = 7).

[2nd attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AxPw.png)

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Python 3.6.1 64bits, Qt 5.6.2, PyQt5 5.6 on Darwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set values to specific columns of a dataframe by using [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and slicing the columns that you need. Then we can set the values using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

A short example using some random data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(4,10)))


   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  7  7  9  4  2  6  6  1  7  9
1  0  1  2  4  5  5  3  9  0  7
2  0  1  4  4  3  8  7  0  6  1
3  1  4  0  2  5  7  2  7  9  9
```

Now we set the region to update and the region we want to update using `iloc`, and we slice columns indexed as 2 to the last column

```
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].where((df < 7) & (df > 2))
```

Which will set the values in the Data Frame to `NaN`.

```
   0  1    2    3    4    5    6   7    8   9
0  7  7  NaN  4.0  NaN  6.0  6.0 NaN  NaN NaN
1  0  1  NaN  4.0  5.0  5.0  3.0 NaN  NaN NaN
2  0  1  4.0  4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN NaN  6.0 NaN
3  1  4  NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

---

For your data the code would be this

```
Data.iloc[:,2:] = Data.iloc[:,2:].where((Data <= 12) & (Data >= -3))
```

---

**Operator clarification**

The setup I show directly above would look like this

`-3 <= Data <= 12`, *gives everything between those numbers*

If we reverse this logic using the `&` operator it looks like this

`-3 >= Data <= 12`, *a number cannot be both less than -3 and greater than 12 at the same time.*

So we use the or operator instead `|`. Code looks like this now....

```
Data.iloc[:,2:] = Data.iloc[:,2:].where((Data >= 12) | (Data <= -3))
```

So the data is checked on a conditional basis

`Data <= -3 or Data >= 12`

Comment: I assume that I have to replace 7 and 2 with -3 and 12 to achieve my desired range.. but when I do this the above code replaces all the values with NaN. This apparently doesn't work for me, but I'm new to Python and don't necessarily know what I'm doing..

Comment: Replace 7 with 12 and 2 with -3.. I think you had it backwards there. Also change the operators appropriately. Sorry about the confusion I have added some info to the answer

Comment: It worked! But why is it '(Data < 12) & (Data > -3)' and not '(Data < -3) & (Data > 12)'? This confuses me, I'm looking for values higher than 12 and lower than -3. Moreover, does this only work if one wants to replace with NaN, what if I wanted to replace them with let say x?

Comment: Ah! that make sense I added a quick explanation to explain the right way to do that logical operation also you could add `.fillna('x')` to the end of that line

Comment: Awesome and clarifying explanation! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `applymap()` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# get the columns after the second one
cols = Data.columns[2:]

# apply mask to those columns
new_df = Data[cols].applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x > 12 or x <= -3 else x)
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

This approach assumes your columns after the second contain `float` or `int` values.

Comment: there's no need to uses `iloc` to get column names. You could simply use `cols= Data.columns[2:]`

Comment: This worked partly, it replaced the invalid values but sliced the dataframe. The " new_df" dataframe only consists of the values and does not contain the needed columns of Ids and Names. I used `pd.concat([Ids, Names, new_df], axis=1)` to merge the data frames giving me the result I orginally desired. Is there anyway to replace theses values and maintain the original dataframe?